# Break out of loop immediately after array is changed

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-requests

This is a little complicated...

Basically, I have this function:

```
def do_loop(self):
    for line in self.connections[0].iter_lines():
            print line
```

And, there is a thread constantly running alongside it, which will at arbitrary times change the value of `connections[0]`.

If this happens, if `connections[0]` is externally changed by the thread, the loop will keep using the old `connections[0]`, I need this to not happen, I need it to immediately use the new `connections[0]` instead.

For some background, `for line in self.connections[0].iter_lines():` is reading data from the Twitter Streaming API using `python-requests`, hence `.iter_lines()`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is going to make an iterator, once, and it won't keep checking `self.connections[0]` in the loop.  So as @mklauber said, use something like `threading.Event`.

Assuming that we have a `threading.Event` instance as `self.new_conn` and it gets set whenever there is a new connection:

```
def do_loop(self):
    for line in self.connections[0].iter_lines():
        if self.new_conn.is_set():
            break # or could raise exception here
        print line
```

If you just need the loop to instantly terminate, you could handle it by making your `.iter_lines()` method a generator, and making the generator do the check:

```
def iter_lines(self):
    for line in self.connections[0].private_data_lines:
        if self.new_conn.is_set():
            break
        yield line
```

This nicely encapsulates the loop.  Your original code would work as shown, and it would stop when there was a new connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following, as a simple solution.  Basically, use a copy of the connection, and check the copy against the source after each loop.

```
def do_loop( self ):
    while true:
        conn = copy( connections[0] )
        for line in conn.iter_lines():
            print line
            if conn != connections[0]:
                break
```

It's not in any way elegant, but without going thorough and redesigning a lot of the code to be threadsafe, it should work.  You can use a `return` statement to leave the while loop, if that is a requirement.

Comment: That's what I originally thought too, but I need the loop to switch immediately to the new connection, it cannot wait for Twitter's API to send new data down the pipe for it to switch, it needs to break immediately after connections[0] is updated.

Comment: Good point.  In that case, you're probably going to need a mutex like object that you can set in one thread and check from another.  I'd recommend an [Event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects).